# CloudFront Lambda@Edge in NodeJS. Layer is not supported for cloudfront. How to use external libraries in edge lambda?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

By using Lambda@Edge inside CloudFront I am not able to install packages thourgh `npm` as `CloudFront` does not allow layers:

**According to AWS doc:**
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-at-edge-function-restrictions.html

[Lambda Features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EujxH.png)

My approach is to validate jwt tokens using Viewer Request

[Functions associated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYK0b.png)

There are multiple examples doing this, and they use common libraries such as:

```
import y from 'jsonwebtoken';
import z from 'jwk-to-pem';
```

But How should be referred if layers are not allowed? Using thus modules the application report errors:

*Cannot find package 'jsonwebtoken' imported from /var/task/index.mjs"*

On the other hand, creating a lambda with a cusotm layer with the following packages worked (But unable to use in aws-cloudfront):

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jwk-to-pem": "^2.0.3",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "jwk-to-pem": "^2.0.5",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21"
  }
}
```

Tried:

- Create a layer on behalf of my lambda@Edge function.

Expected to happen:

- Validate tokens in AWS@Lambda edge functions with external 3rd parties.

Actually result:

- Layers are not allowed in AWS@Lambda

Answer (score 1):

I was able to create the package without using a layer.

Solution: Deploy it as a zip file

Considerations: There is a maximum file size when using it in Lambda@Edge cloudfront.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-package.html